# Model for predicting medical outcomes on longitudinal data? Even with uneven time steps?

Tags: neural-networks, python, random-forest, lstm

I have a dataset that originated from medical claims that has one subject/person on multiple rows, along with when the person visited the doctor, and all the diagnoses the person received during that visit. Also included are some other factors, like age. An example is given below:

```
+----+------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| ID |    Date    |         Diag_1       |         Diag_2          |   Diag_3 |  age  |
+----+------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
| A  | 12/1/19    |   obesity            |    high blood pressure. |          |    59 |
| A  | 12/14/19   | high blood pressure  | difficulty breathing    |          |    59 |
| A  |    2/1/20  |  high blood pressure |                         |          |    59 |
| B  |    5/3/18  |  arm pain            |  broken wrist           |          |    34 |
| B  |    5/6/18  |  arm pain            |  broken wrist           |          |    34 |
| C  |    6/6/19. | headaches            |  trouble sleeping       |          |    41 |
| C  |    7/1/19  |  trouble sleeping    |                         |          |    41 |
| C  |    7/20/19 | trouble sleeping     |                         |          |    41 |
+----+------------+----------------------+-------------------------+----------+-------+
```

My question is, what kind of model can I use to help predict, given a person's data from above, if they'd likely visit the doctor again in the next 90 days / the probability of visiting again in 90 days? If that question is too hard to solve, I'm open to other related variations, like when their next visit might be.

I've seen posts mention using LSTMs on this kind of longitudinal data, but I'm not sure if that's still viable since the time steps on the Date are not even (e.g. person A waits 13 days between his first and second visit, then waits almost 50 days between his second and third visit).

I've also seen some mentions of "flattening" the data so that one person will only be on one row, and then using a classification method like random forests since we've removed correlation between rows.

Is there any sort of model that can help me with this?